# CloudFormation - Unable to return input into response body for GET method

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to update my CloudFormation stack to return the inputs values into the Response Body, but so far it always returns empty.  The end goal is to use this API Gateway to make a GET request to a table to return back those values.  I'be been looking throughout SO and AWS site but haven't found a solution.
Thanks for the help!

Below is the CF code I'm trying to update, the basic lambda code, and the response I DO get when I test the code in Lambda, followed by the response I get when I test in the API.

- [Create API gateway in localstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44547574/create-api-gateway-in-localstack/48682628#48682628)
- https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/9271
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-integration-settings-integration-response.html
- https://forums.aws.amazon.com/search.jspa?q=return%20method%20response%20body%20%20cloudformation&objID=f199&dateRange=all&searchID=12328864&forumID=199&rankBy=10001&start=15
  [Amazon APi gateway fails to generate transformed request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33516225/amazon-api-gateway-fails-to-generate-transformed-request)

'

```
ApiGatewayMethodGetDefaultInputs:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
        ApiKeyRequired: false
        RequestParameters:
            method.request.querystring.filter: true
        AuthorizationType: NONE
        HttpMethod: GET
        Integration:
            ConnectionType: INTERNET
            IntegrationResponses:
                - StatusCode: !Ref StatusCode
                  SelectionPattern: '-'
                  ResponseParameters:
                    method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: !Ref CorsHeaders
                    method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: !Ref CorsMethodsGet
                    method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: !Ref CorsOrigin
                  ResponseTemplates:
                    application/json: |
                        body : $input.json('$')

            # Credentials: !Ref ApiGatewayIamRole
            IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
            PassthroughBehavior: WHEN_NO_MATCH
            TimeoutInMillis: 29000
            Type: AWS
            Uri: !Sub 'arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${WFOGetDefaultInputsArn}/invocations'
        MethodResponses:
            - StatusCode: !Ref StatusCode
              ResponseModels:
                application/json: 'Empty'
              ResponseParameters:
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'*'"
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'*'"
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: !Ref CorsOrigin
        OperationName: !Ref OperationName
        ResourceId: !Ref ApiGatewayResourceGetDefaultInputs
        RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayRestApi
```

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(event),
        'headers': {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    }

{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "{\"id\": 1234}",
  "headers": {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
}


body : {"statusCode":200,"body":"{}","headers":{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*","Content-Type":"application/json"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through some trial and error I was able to get the GET function working when I created the Body Mapping Template.  Once that was working I figured out in order to create the Mapping Template I needed to add a RequestTemplates parameter to my Integration param.

```
            RequestTemplates:
                application/json: |
                    {
                        "id": $input.params('id')
                    }
```

After adding these in the function works as expected.